# Total differentiation equation concerning homogeneous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I was asked to prove the following statement:

> Suppose $P(x,y),Q(x,y)$ are both $n$-th homogeneous functions ($n\ne-1$), i.e., 
>   $$P(tx,ty)=t^nP(x,y),\, Q(tx,ty)=t^nQ(x,y)\quad\forall t\in\Bbb R$$
>   and that 
>   $$P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$$
>   is a **total differentiation equation**, prove that its solution is
>   $$xP(x,y)+yQ(x,y)=C$$
>   where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

My approach, however, seemed to disagree with this conclusion:
Since $Pdx+Qdy=0$ is a total differentiation equation, we have $P_y=Q_x$. Suppose $dU=Pdx+Qdy$, then the solution is clearly $U=C$. Therefore $U=xP+yQ$ and 
$$U_x=P+xP_x+yQ_x=P+xP_x+yP_y$$
But $U_x=P$ according to $dU=Pdx+Qdy$, so all we have to do is to prove
$$xP_x+yP_y=0$$
However, according to [Euler's Homogeneous Function Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html), we ought to have
$$xP_x+yP_y=nP$$
which does not make sense to me..

Is there anything wrong in my approach? Or the statement itself is just not correct?

Comment: I think you should consider the test case $P=x$ and $Q=y$. Then your solution becomes $x^2+y^2=0$. But if you plug in the left directly, you get $2xdx+2ydx\neq xdx+ydy$.

Comment: @Chanler this is a problem. So how am I supposed to make use of the total DE?

Comment: Its really a matter of convention. When you compute the total derivative of your $U$, you end up with the correct equation, you just have to actor something out. That is $x^2+y^2=C$, apply $d$, get $2xdx+2ydy=0$ so $xdx+ydy$. You actually have stated the needed result to!